# Rails Heroku deploy / initializer / belongs_to_required_by_default=false not being respected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, belongs-to

I've hit a very strange case which for the life of my I can't figure out:

I have a Rails5 app on Heroku that is throwing validation errors in production (not in local development or test) for models based on nil values on `belongs_to` foreign key columns.

I'm well aware of the change in Rails5 behavior per [this post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) that makes `belongs_to` required by default, but I turned this off as a validation requirement by setting `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false`
 in a `new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb` initializer - I added this file/line when I completed the Rails5 upgrade months ago and it's been working dandy since...until now when this behavior just now started occurring on my most recent Heroku deploy.

What's especially bizarre is:

1. I haven't changed any code in the relevant model or initializer files - this regression started occurring on an unrelated feature deploy (I've scoured the commits to make extra sure)
2. I can't repro locally in development - the same exact branch it works as expected with the `belongs_to` not being required for model validation
3. I can't seem to repro in production `rails console` either - m = Model.new; m.valid? returns true (despite having nil belongs_to column ids) which is not the behavior triggered by the web app ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

So I'm stumped/spooked and wonder if anyone has wisdom. It feels like it's got to be related to how/if Heroku is loading the relevant initializer file during boot that may have changed recently?

Comment: Hi, can you share your github project? is the name of the Model Model? did you run the console in `heroku production`?

Comment: it's a private repo, so I can't share - I did run `heroku production` console and was not able to repro the issue

Comment: please show us from your `production` postgresql database the information about those 2 tables. What about including `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false` in your `production.rb`